# State of a thread after it is terminated

Tags: c, multithreading, rtos, cmsis

In which state is a thread when it is terminated with the "osThreadTerminate" function?

Here is the function:

```
void High_Thread(void const *argument)
{
  while(1)
  {
   GPIOE->DOUT_BYTE=0xFF;
   osThreadTerminate(ThreadId_high
  }
}
```

Comment: ?? How can something that no longer exists have a state?  Your question makes no sense:(

Comment: https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/cmsis/RTOS/html/group__CMSIS__RTOS__ThreadMgmt.html

Comment: better say what you want to archive

Comment: There is a question about a task which asks what status the thread is in after calling "osThreadTerminated". Then there are the following statuses: "Not Created, Running, Ready, Waiting, Inactive, Suspend". One of them is the answer

Comment: @MartinJames, You assume that a "thread" no longer exists after it terminates. I would not. The OP appears to be asking about CMSIS-RTOS. I don't know CMSIS, but there can be good reason for a _handle_ to something like a thread to continue to exist even after the thing that the handle represents has "terminated" (or "expired," or "closed," ...) Often, the good reason is just so that the program can ask about the state. Think of Unix processes, where a "terminated" process continues to exist as a "zombie" until its parent process explicitly `wait()`s for its termination status.

Answer (score 0):

It is CMSIS RTOS. Threads are simple functions that do not return. When you delete the thread (I think the better name is the task in this case), the task stack and TCB (Task control block) is being removed from the RTOS heap.

The removed task does not exist and it is not in any state. The code of the task is not changed as it resides in the non-volatile memory (FLASH)

`phthreads` do not have anything in common with CMSIS RTOS and I have removed this tag.

Comment: does it mean that a thread has no status after it has ended? But it should have one according to the task: D
One of them:
Not Created, Running, Ready, Waiting, Inactive, Suspend

Comment: Inactive state means that the task does not exist.

Comment: also is the thread in the inactive state after it is terminated?